# Query multiindex dataframe to differentiate entries in and not in

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, multi-index

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
FirstDF=
              C
A    B      
'a' 'blue'   43
    'green'  59
'b' 'red     56
'c' 'green'  80
    'orange' 72
```

Where A and B are set as indexes. I also have a DataFrame that looks like:

```
SecondDF=

    A     B
0  'a'  'green'
1  'b'  'red'
2  'c'  'green'
```

Is there a way I can directly query FirstDF with the last one, and obtain an output like the following?

```
C
59
56
80
```

I also need to obtain the values that are not in SecondDF:

```
C
43
72
```

I did it by iterating over the index of FirstDF, as shown below, but I would like to do it using pandas logic instead of for loops.

```
ins=[]
outs=[]
for i in FirstDF.index:
    if i in zip(SecondDF['A'],SecondDF['B']):
        ins.append(i)
    else:
        outs.append(i)

insDF = FirstDF.loc[ins]
outsDF = FirstDF.loc[outs]
```

However, this approach leads to inconsistent results with a big data set because in my case the outsDF dataframe has more entries than the original dataframe FirstDF.

I also tried something like this:

```
insDF = FirstDF.loc[zip(SecondDF['A'],SecondDF['B'])]
outsDF = FirstDF.loc[~zip(SecondDF['A'],SecondDF['B'])]
```

But it raises an error.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

you can set col A and B in df2 as the index and then merge:

```
df2.set_index(['A', 'B'], inplace=True)
pd.merge(df1,df2,left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

out:

```
            C
A   B   
a   green   59
b   red     56
c   green   80
```

Comment: I also need to get the values that are not in df2, any idea?

Comment: try this,  `df1[~df1.isin(df2).all(axis=1)]`

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can try below using Pandas `merge` :

```
>>> pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['A', 'B'])['C']
0    59
1    56
2    80
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

**OR**

```
>>> df = df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_on=['A','B'])['C'].to_frame()
>>> df
    C
0  59
1  56
2  80
```

**and**

```
>>> pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['A', 'B'])
   A      B   C
0  a  green  59
1  b    red  56
2  c  green  80
```

Comment: I also need to get the values that are not in df2, any idea?

Comment: @AndrésMarulanda, you values are in df1 but not in df2?